# Find value based on intersection between row and column

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have two tables (sorry, I do not know how to format table here):

First one (calculated values):

```
Contract        RD            AGE
=================================
194306          A0TO30      60TO71
196797          A50TO70     60TO71
197206          A50TO70     60TO71
198381          A70TO90     60TO71
198419          A150TO200   60TO71
229896          A0TO30      12TO23
41009438        A70TO90     12TO23
41009448        A0TO30      12TO23
```

And the second one (fixed values)

```
    Interval            12TO23     24TO35     36TO47  48TO59  60TO71  72TO83
============================================================================  
    A0TO30              0,85       0,75       0,65    0,55    0,5     0,45
    A30TO50             0,87       0,8        0,75    0,7     0,65    0,6
    A50TO70             0,9        0,85       0,8     0,75    0,7     0,65
    A70TO90             1          0,95       0,9     0,85    0,85    0,85
    A90TO150            1,2        1,15       1,1     1,05    1,05    1,05
    A150TO200           1,3        1,25       1,2     1,15    1,1     1,1
```

What I need is, for example, when for contract 194306 RD=A0TO30 and AGE=60TO71
to obtain the value 0,5 (at the intersection of 1st row and 1st column)
For contract 198381 the result should be 0,85 and so on.
I can do it with CASE for every value in RD, but if I ever need to change the coefficients from the second table it would take a lot of time and I might make mistakes.

The result should look like this

```
Contract      Coefficient
====================
194306        0,5
196797        0,7
197206        0,7
198381        0,85
198419        1,1
```

I didn't try anything because frankly, I do not know wehere to start.
I did it with CASE like

```
CASE WHEN RD BETWEEN 0 and 30 THEN
     CASE WHEN AGE BETWEEN 12 and 23 THEN 0,85
          WHEN AGE BETWEEN 24 and 35 THEN 0,75
```

... and so on for each interval in RD

For RD 'A0TO30' actually means RD between 0% and 30% and
for AGE 12TO23 means between 12 and 23 months.

Comment: Can you show your expected results in your question as well please (based on the sample data you have)? What attempt(s) have you made and why didn't they work? When you edit your question to include your expected resultset please do include your attempt(s) too.

Comment: You would use a join to get the rows lined up. But the biggest concern here is normalization. Your second table seems to have a column for every possible value which violates 1NF.

Comment: Sorry, fr the first form of the post.

Comment: The second table contains coefficients. The contract is tested against both conditions in the first table (RD and AGE) and should return the value where the two intersects. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the data in one table references schema names in the other, you can use dynamic SQL to write the query and execute it with sp_executesql:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sql = (
SELECT STUFF(
    (SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT ' + CAST(Contract AS VARCHAR(25)) + ' AS Contract, ' + 
     '(SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(AGE) + ' FROM t2 WHERE Interval = t1.RD) AS Coefficient ' + 
     'FROM t1 WHERE contract = ' + CAST(Contract AS VARCHAR(25))
FROM t1
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 11, '')
)

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

Returns:

```
Contract    Coefficient
194306      0,5
196797      0,7
197206      0,7
198381      0,85
198419      1,1
229896      0,85
41009438    1
41009448    0,85
```

(Sample Data)

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (Contract INT, RD VARCHAR(25), AGE VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES 
(194306      ,'A0TO30'      ,'60TO71'),
(196797      ,'A50TO70'     ,'60TO71'),
(197206      ,'A50TO70'     ,'60TO71'),
(198381      ,'A70TO90'     ,'60TO71'),
(198419      ,'A150TO200'   ,'60TO71'),
(229896      ,'A0TO30'      ,'12TO23'),
(41009438    ,'A70TO90'     ,'12TO23'),
(41009448    ,'A0TO30'      ,'12TO23')

CREATE TABLE t2 (Interval VARCHAR(25), [12TO23] varchar(10), [24TO35] varchar(10), [36TO47] varchar(10), [48TO59] varchar(10), [60TO71] varchar(10), [72TO33] varchar(10))
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES 
('A0TO30'   ,'0,85','0,75','0,65','0,55','0,5','0,45'),
('A30TO50'  ,'0,87','0,8', '0,75','0,7','0,65','0,6'),
('A50TO70'  ,'0,9' ,'0,85','0,8','0,75','0,7','0,65'),
('A70TO90'  ,'1'   ,'0,95','0,9','0,85','0,85','0,85'),
('A90TO150' ,'1,2' ,'1,15','1,1','1,05','1,05','1,05'),
('A150TO200','1,3' ,'1,25','1,2','1,15','1,1','1,1')
```